# Java Addition Throws Error As Null

Tags: java, math

I'm sorry to bother you busy people with this probably obvious question, but the compiler wont give me anything except:

```
Arithmetic.java:4: error: null: 146367789778966
        int myNumber = 3 + 146367789778966;
        ^                 
           1 error
```

> Code

```
public class Arithmetic {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int myNumber = 3 + 146367789778966;
    System.out.println(myNumber);

    }
}
```

If anyone can tell me whats wrong, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is actually `2147483647`
- `146367789778966`  is bigger than  `Integer.MAX_VALUE`  so it cannot be stored in `int` type

An `IDE` like IntelliJ will warn you about this :

```
Error:(10, 28) java: integer number too large: 146367789778966 // what IntelliJ gives me
```

---

You can use for ex `BigInteger` :

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("146367789778966");
b = b.add(BigInteger.valueOf(3));
System.out.println(b)       // 146367789778969
```

Comment: but it doesn't. Read the error, it throws null. Thats My problem now

Answer (score 4):

146367789778966 is too large to fit in an `int` type.

The max value an `int` can hold is 2,147,483,647 so the value can't fit inside the `int` and your code throws the error.

You could use a larger data type like `long`.

More information on data types:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: I just don't know why it would error as null... probably just something wrong with the installation.

Comment: Me either - I get  "error: integer number too large: 999999999999"

Comment: Oh well, ill call my IDE's support or something, thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

The max value for an int is 2,147,483,647.
So your number is just too darn big.